# numpy.float64 object is not callable error on concrete dataset

Tags: python, keras

I'm writing a simple Regression Model in Keras for predicting Strength.

This is my code:

```
epochs_number = 50
mean_squared_errors = []
number_of_reapeat = 50

for i in range(0, number_of_reapeat):
    print(i)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(predictors, target, test_size=0.3, random_state=i)
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs_number, verbose=0)
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    mean_squared_error = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
    mean_squared_errors.append(mean_squared_error)
```

But whenever I run this code , following error shown :

```
0
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [11], line 10
      8 model.fit(X_train , y_train , epochs=epochs_number , verbose=0)
      9 y_pred= model.predict(X_test)
---> 10 mean_squared_error = mean_squared_error(y_test,y_pred)
     11 mean_squared_errors.append(mean_squared_error)

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

What is problem and How can I solve it??

Comment: you may want to use metrics.mean_squared_error and rename then var to something else 
mean_squared_errors = [] to mean_sq_err = []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You presumably have a function named `mean_squared_error()`, but in your loop you just assigned its output to a variable of the same name.

Comment: or other way around. it may be typo.